# Why won't my simple regex pattern match and remove a file extension?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string:

```
app_copy--28.ipa
```

The result I want is:

```
app_copy
```

The number after `--` could be of variable length, so I want to match everything including and after `--`.

I've tried a few patterns, but none are matching for some reason:

```
gsub("--\*", "")
gsub("--*", "")
gsub("--*.ipa", "")
gsub("--\[0-9].ipa", "")
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a look at your test patterns:

- `"--\*"` is actually equivalent to `"--*"` (since the `\*` is an escape sequence).
- `"--*"` will match a single `-` character, followed by zero or more `-` characters.
- `"--*.ipa"` will match a single `-` character, followed by zero or more `-` characters, followed by any single character, followed by a literal `ipa`.
- `"--\[0-9].ipa"` is actually equivalent to `"--[0-9].ipa"` (since the `\[` is an escape sequence), which will match a literal `--`, followed by a single decimal digit, followed by any single character, followed by a literal `ipa`.

However, none of these patterns would work as you used them because [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) will not treat it as a regular expression:

> The pattern is typically a `Regexp`; if given as a `String`, any regular expression metacharacters it contains will be interpreted literally…

You'd need to wrap type convert your pattern to a `Regexp` (using [`Regexp.new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#method-c-new)), or use a [regular expression literal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Regular+Expressions).

Try this pattern

```
--.*
```

This pattern will find any literal `--`, followed by zero or more of any character.

For example:

```
"app_copy--28.ipa".gsub(/--.*/, "")     # app_copy
```

Comment: `"app_copy--28.ipa".gsub("--.*", "")` yields the same as original input.

Comment: @maq ahh, sorry, it needs to be a regex literal (`/.../`), see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `gsub` to try to change the string, simply use a pattern to match the part you want:

```
"app_copy--28.ipa"[/^(.+?)--/, 1] # => "app_copy"
```

String's [`[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) takes a lot of different types of parameters. You can pass in a pattern, and the index of the capture that you want, to extract just that part. From the documentation:

```
str[regexp, capture] → new_str or nil
```

> If a Regexp is supplied, the matching portion of the string is returned. If a capture follows the regular expression, which may be a capture group index or name, follows the regular expression that component of the MatchData is returned instead.

Answer (score 1):

How is this ?

```
str = "app_copy--28.ipa"
str[0..str.index("-")-1]
# => "app_copy"

str = "app_copy--28.ipa"
str.split("--").first
# => "app_copy"
```